# Distinguishing among multiple syslog docker sources

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, docker-compose, syslog

I am setting up a `docker-compose` with several services, all of them writing to a common `syslog` container / service... which actually is a `logstash` service (a complete `elk` image as a matter of fact) with the `logstash-input-syslog` plugin enabled..

kind of as follows (using custom `5151` port since default `514` was giving me a hard time due to permission issues):

services:

```
  elk-custom:
    image: some_elk_image
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
      - 9200:9200
      - 5044:5044
      - 5151:5151

  service1:
     image: myservice1_image
     logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:5151"

  service2:
     image: myservice2_image
     logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:5151"
```

My question is how can I add a field (an `option` rather under `logging`) so that each log entry in `logstash` ends up with a field, whose value will help determine whether the log came from `service1` or `service2`.

I kind of managed to do this using the `tag` field, but the information ends up being part of the message, and not a separate field which I can use for queries in `elasticsearch`.
For the time being, `kibana` displays log entries as follows:

> @timestamp:September 26th 2017, 12:00:47.684 syslog_severity_code:5
>   port:53,422 syslog_facility:user-level @version:1 host:172.18.0.1
>   syslog_facility_code:1 message:<27>Sep 26 12:00:47 7705a2f9b22a[2128]:
>   [pid: 94|app: 0|req: 4/7] 172.18.0.1 () {40 vars in 461 bytes} [Tue
>   Sep 26 09:00:47 2017] GET /api/v1/apikeys => generated 74 bytes in 5
>   msecs (HTTP/1.1 401) 2 headers in 81 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
>   type:syslog syslog_severity:notice tags:_grokparsefailure
>   _id:AV69atD4zBS_tKzDPfyh _type:syslog _index:logstash-2017.09.26 _score: -

From what I also know, we cannot define custom `syslog-facilities` since they are predefined by the syslog RFC.

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using port multiplexing and adding custom field based on this condition:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
elk-custom:
    image: some_elk_image
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
      - 9200:9200
      - 5044:5044
      - 5151:5151
      - 5152:5152

  service1:
     image: myservice2_image
     logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:5151"

  service2:
     image: myservice2_image
     logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:5152"
```

`logstash-conf`

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5151
    type => syslog
    add_field => {'received_from' => 'service1'}
  }

  tcp {
    port => 5152
    type => syslog
    add_field => {'received_from' => 'service2'}
  }
}
```